# Function in external javascript file called only on reload In react js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, webpack

I have a external js file linked to my html  and bundle.js file generated by webpack linked to html .

In index.html code is

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.min.js"></script>`
```

The issue is functions in main.js are called only once on page load in reactjs after running webpack and code is bundled.

main.js file code is

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    var isMobile = {
        Android: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
        },
            BlackBerry: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
        },
            iOS: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
        },
            Opera: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
        },
            Windows: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
        },
            any: function() {
            return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
        }
    };

    var mobileMenuOutsideClick = function() {

        $(document).click(function (e) {
        var container = $("#fh5co-offcanvas, .js-fh5co-nav-toggle");
        if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {

            if ( $('body').hasClass('offcanvas') ) {

                $('body').removeClass('offcanvas');
                $('.js-fh5co-nav-toggle').removeClass('active');

            }


        }
        });

    };


    var offcanvasMenu = function() {

        $('#page').prepend('<div id="fh5co-offcanvas" />');
        $('#page').prepend('<a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-white"><i></i></a>');
        var clone1 = $('.menu-1 > ul').clone();
        $('#fh5co-offcanvas').append(clone1);
        var clone2 = $('.menu-2 > ul').clone();
        $('#fh5co-offcanvas').append(clone2);

        $('#fh5co-offcanvas .has-dropdown').addClass('offcanvas-has-dropdown');
        $('#fh5co-offcanvas')
            .find('li')
            .removeClass('has-dropdown');

        // Hover dropdown menu on mobile
        $('.offcanvas-has-dropdown').mouseenter(function(){
            var $this = $(this);

            $this
                .addClass('active')
                .find('ul')
                .slideDown(500, 'easeOutExpo');
        }).mouseleave(function(){

            var $this = $(this);
            $this
                .removeClass('active')
                .find('ul')
                .slideUp(500, 'easeOutExpo');
        });


        $(window).resize(function(){

            if ( $('body').hasClass('offcanvas') ) {

                $('body').removeClass('offcanvas');
                $('.js-fh5co-nav-toggle').removeClass('active');

            }
        });
    };


    var burgerMenu = function() {

        $('body').on('click', '.js-fh5co-nav-toggle', function(event){
            var $this = $(this);


            if ( $('body').hasClass('overflow offcanvas') ) {
                $('body').removeClass('overflow offcanvas');
            } else {
                $('body').addClass('overflow offcanvas');
            }
            $this.toggleClass('active');
            event.preventDefault();

        });
    };

    var fullHeight = function() {

        if ( !isMobile.any() ) {
            $('.js-fullheight').css('height', $(window).height());
            $(window).resize(function(){
                $('.js-fullheight').css('height', $(window).height());
            });
        }

    };



    var contentWayPoint = function() {
        var i = 0;
        $('.animate-box').waypoint( function( direction ) {

            if( direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated-fast') ) {

                i++;

                $(this.element).addClass('item-animate');
                setTimeout(function(){

                    $('body .animate-box.item-animate').each(function(k){
                        var el = $(this);
                        setTimeout( function () {
                            var effect = el.data('animate-effect');
                            if ( effect === 'fadeIn') {
                                el.addClass('fadeIn animated-fast');
                            } else if ( effect === 'fadeInLeft') {
                                el.addClass('fadeInLeft animated-fast');
                            } else if ( effect === 'fadeInRight') {
                                el.addClass('fadeInRight animated-fast');
                            } else {
                                el.addClass('fadeInUp animated-fast');
                            }

                            el.removeClass('item-animate');
                        },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );
                    });

                }, 100);

            }

        } , { offset: '85%' } );
    };


    var dropdown = function() {

        $('.has-dropdown').mouseenter(function(){

            var $this = $(this);
            $this
                .find('.dropdown')
                .css('display', 'block')
                .addClass('animated-fast fadeInUpMenu');

        }).mouseleave(function(){
            var $this = $(this);

            $this
                .find('.dropdown')
                .css('display', 'none')
                .removeClass('animated-fast fadeInUpMenu');
        });

    };


    var goToTop = function() {

        $('.js-gotop').on('click', function(event){

            event.preventDefault();

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('html').offset().top
            }, 500, 'easeInOutExpo');

            return false;
        });

        $(window).scroll(function(){

            var $win = $(window);
            if ($win.scrollTop() > 200) {
                $('.js-top').addClass('active');
            } else {
                $('.js-top').removeClass('active');
            }

        });

    };


    // Loading page
    var loaderPage = function() {
        $(".fh5co-loader").fadeOut("slow");
    };

    var counter = function() {
        $('.js-counter').countTo({
             formatter: function (value, options) {
          return value.toFixed(options.decimals);
        },
        });
    };

    var counterWayPoint = function() {
        if ($('#fh5co-counter').length > 0 ) {
            $('#fh5co-counter').waypoint( function( direction ) {

                if( direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated') ) {
                    setTimeout( counter , 400);
                    $(this.element).addClass('animated');
                }
            } , { offset: '90%' } );
        }
    };

    var parallax = function() {

        if ( !isMobile.any() ) {
            $(window).stellar({
                horizontalScrolling: false,
                hideDistantElements: false,
                responsive: true

            });
        }
    };

    var testimonialCarousel = function(){

        var owl = $('.owl-carousel-fullwidth');
        owl.owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            loop: true,
            margin: 0,
            nav: false,
            dots: true,
            smartSpeed: 800,
            autoHeight: true
        });
    };

    var sliderMain = function() {

        $('#fh5co-hero .flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "fade",
            slideshowSpeed: 5000,
            directionNav: true,
            start: function(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.slider-text').removeClass('animated fadeInUp');
                    $('.flex-active-slide').find('.slider-text').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
                }, 500);
            },
            before: function(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.slider-text').removeClass('animated fadeInUp');
                    $('.flex-active-slide').find('.slider-text').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
                }, 500);
            }

        });

        $('#fh5co-hero .flexslider .slides > li').css('height', $(window).height());
        $(window).resize(function(){
            $('#fh5co-hero .flexslider .slides > li').css('height', $(window).height());
        });

    };


    $(function(){
        mobileMenuOutsideClick();
        offcanvasMenu();
        burgerMenu();
        contentWayPoint();
        sliderMain();
        dropdown();
        goToTop();
        loaderPage();
        counterWayPoint();
        counter();
        parallax();
        testimonialCarousel();
        fullHeight();
    });


}());
```

I want my code in main.js called always not only on reload. I am using reactjs and webpack.
Please help me fix this. Thank you.

Comment: Did you consider add your functions as (module) for example Utils... In your bundle? On this way you could be executing on demand..

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you your code in `main.js` is wrapped in something like this:

```
(function () {
    ...
}());
```

Above construction is called `Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)` - it makes code inside to be called immediately and because everything defined inside  any function is visible only in this function (is not visible outside function scope) it also  helps to not pollute global context. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript). 
If you want to have possibility to call it anytime you need you should use normal function (not `IIFE`):

```
function mainFunction() {
    //your codde
}
```

and then you can call it anytime you need (also on page load).

Comment: Can you me where to the call the function . In react component or somewhere else.

Comment: Well, it really depends on your application. Since your function accesses many DOM elements you should call it when those elements are available on your page.. but it depends on your React components logic. Generally I'd suggest to initialize each of plugin (owlCarousel, flexslider..) inside  components responsible for markup related to them. You can call them in `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` hooks